# How do I increment a counter in an XSL doc, and then display the value in parenthese after a hyperlink

Tags: xml, xslt, asp-classic

Basically, I need to add to a counter how many courses (activities) for each instructor per month.  From the XSL below - you will see that the date is being checked, and if the course date is between the dates, then the course name displays, and one should be added to the counter.  If not, white space will show on the counter.
Here it is:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when>
    <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($activities)">
      <xsl:if test="number(translate(startdate, '-', '')) &lt;= number(translate($thisDate, '/', '')) and  number(translate(enddate, '-', '')) &gt;= number(translate($thisDate, '/', ''))">
        <xsl:variable name="lngItemID">
          <xsl:value-of select="activityid" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:call-template name="ShowActivityForDate">
          <xsl:with-param name="lstActivity" select="current()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Then, the counter value, in parentheses, needs to show right after the instructor name, which is a hyperlink:
(The calendar is a table that has a list of instructors - as a link - and one month's data, strung along from 1-31 for that month - with a course name, or white).

```
<td valign="center" class="tableentry">
  <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
       javascript:OpenMetadata(244,'U','<xsl:value-of select="$lstactivities[1]/instructorid" />','','MDT','width=600,height=650,left=50,top=50,resizable=no');
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="$lstactivities[1]/instructor" />
  </xsl:element> 
</td>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please check the formatting of your post ... most of your code was invisible until I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't increment counters in XSLT; each "variable" is really a constant. However you can count things using `count()` and an XPath expression, possibly using predicates. E.g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(msxsl:node-set($activities)[
   number(translate(startdate, '-', '')) &lt;= number(translate($thisDate, '/', '')) and
   number(translate(enddate, '-', '')) &gt;= number(translate($thisDate, '/', ''))
])" />
```

Comment: This didn't work - my screen came up blank..not sure why. I guess I need to have a better understanding of the how the count function works.
Also - what about the second part of a the question - a space after the hyperlink, before the text.  thanks.

Comment: @user3407601: a `value-of` with a `count()` function should always output a number, even if it's zero. So apparently your `value-of` is not being reached. There's no way to diagnose that without seeing your stylesheet and input document.

Comment: @user3407601: to output a space, put a space in your stylesheet. I think you're asking how to do the right conditional, but I don't understand (based on your question) *when* a space should be added. Once for each course that is *not* between a specified pair of dates? If so, change your `xsl:if` to a `xsl:choose` with a `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise`. That lets you do what other languages call if/then/else.